# Collection processing or database request ? which one is better

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, stream

This is my first post on stackoverflow, so please be nice to me :-)

So let me explain the context. I'm developing a web service with a standard layer (resources, services, DAO Layer...). I use JPA with hibernate implementation for my object model with the database.

For a class A parent and a class B child, most of the time when i want to find an object B on the collection, I use the streamAPI to filter the collection based on what i want. My question here is more general, is it better to search an object by requesting the database (from my point of view this gonna cause a lot of calls to the database but it's gonna use less CPU), or do the opposite by searching over the model object and process over collection (this gonna cause less database calls, but more CPU process)

Comment: Do calculation always as close to the data as possible. In your case - if you can filter in the database - do it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider latency, the database *will* always be slower.

So you gotta ask yourself some questions:

- how far away is the database (latency)?
- how big is the dataset?
- How do I process them ?

  - do I have any major runtime issues ?

> from my point of view this gonna cause a lot of calls to the database but it's gonna use less CPU), or do the opposite by searching over the model object and process over collection (**this gonna cause less database calls, but more CPU process**)

You're program is probably not very performant programmed. I suggest you check the [O-Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) if you have any major runtime leaks.

Your Question is very broad, so it's hard to tell you, for your use-case, which might be the best.

Comment: thanks for the answer. actually i'm still developing the webservice. is not in production yet so i can't answer the last one question. this webService is going to be used for an internal company network (db,appserver are going to be on the same building i guess) so i don't think latency is going to be an issue. All collections object process are going to be small (20-30 entity max)

Answer (score 0):

Use database to return data what you need and Java to perform processing on them that would be complicated to do in a JPQL/SQL query.

Databases are designed to perform queries more efficiently than Java (stream or no).
Besides, fetching many data from a database to finally keep only a part of them is not efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the thing is that i know more or less the size of my collections (rarely more than 20 elements by collection). is still worth it to make a request in DB for so little gain ?

Comment: You are welcome. Otherwise, how do you want to proceed ? You want query all the table ?

Comment: If i take the example i mentioned on my post, i'm gonna access to a specific B class object Using the collection setter of his parent -> classA.listB.stream.filter(predicate).... I'm not really sure if i understood your question,

Answer (score 0):

The database is usually faster since it is optimized for requesting specific data. Usually one would add indexes to speed up querying on certain fields.

TLDR: Filter your data in the database and process them from java.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an easy question to answer, since there are many different factors that would influence my decision to go to the db or not. First, I think it's fair to say that, for almost every app I've worked on in the past 20 years, hitting the DB for information is the default strategy. More recently (say past 10 or so years) data access through web service calls has become common as well.

For me, the main question would be something along the lines of, "Are there any situations when I would not hit an external resource (DB, Service, or even file read) for data every time I need it?"

So, I'll outline some of the things I would consider.

**Is the data search space very small?**

If you are searching a data space of tens of different records, then this information might be a candidate for non-db storage. On the other hand, once you get past a fairly small set records, this approach becomes increasingly untenable. Examples of these "small sets" might be something like salutations (Mr., Ms., Dr., Mrs., Lord). I looks for small sets of data that rarely change, which I, as a lazy developer, wouldn't mind typing into a configuration file. Once I get past something like 50 different records (like US States, for example), I want to pull that info from a DB or service call.

**Are the data cacheable?**

If you have multiple requests that could legitimately use the exact same data, then leverage caching in your application. Examine the data and expected usage of your service for opportunities to leverage regularities in data and likely requests to cache data whenever possible. Remember to consider cache keys, how long items should be cached, and when cached items should be evicted.

In many web usage scenarios, it's not uncommon that each display could include a fairly large amount of cached information, and a small amount of dynamic data. Menu and other navigation items are good candidates for caching. User-specific data, such as contract-sepcific pricing in an eCommerce app are often poor candidates.

**Can you pre-load some data into cache?**

Some items can be read once and cached for the entire duration of your application. A list of US States and/or Canadian Provinces is a good example here. These almost never change, so once read from the db, you would rarely need to read them again. Consider application components that can load such data on startup, and then hold this data in an appropriate collection.